# Remote Debugging of Tomcat/Wildfly server in docker container in VSCode/Intellij

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, tomcat, intellij-idea, wildfly

I want to remote debug a Java application in Wildfly/Tomcat embedded in a
Docker container. I want to debug the application in VsCode; I also tried to remote debug in IntelliJ. For both I am getting the same error:

```
Error running 'Tomcat in Docker': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:9000): java.net.SocketException "Connection reset"
```

docker-compose

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
   wildfly:
      image: jboss/wildfly:latest
      ports:
        - 8088:8080
        - 9990:9990
        - 8787:8787
      entrypoint: "/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 --debug"
   tomcat:
     image: tomcat:10
     environment:
       - JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
       - JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
     ports:
       - 8888:8080
       - 9000:8000
     entrypoint: "/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh jpda run"
```

launch.json in VsCode

```json
{
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Attach Wildfly",
        "request": "attach",
        "hostName": "localhost",
        "port": "8787"
      }, 
      {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Attach Tomcat",
        "request": "attach",
        "hostName": "localhost",
        "port": "9000"
      }
  ]
}
```

```sh
netstat -tuplen | grep 8787

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8787            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          257375     -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::8787                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          257380     -
```

```sh
netstat -tuplen | grep 9000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          255587     -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          253926     -
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You say, the app is remote, though you point your IDEs to localhost. Where is your container running? Is it localhost or remote? What OS? Do you have access to that machine? Can you check what ports are being listened? Is docker-compose running successfully?

Comment: I need to remote-debug the application, but it's on my local computer. The OS is Linux. Yes, it's my local machine, so I have access. Yes docker-compose is running, the application is up.

Comment: I can connect to both servers with telnet

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when trying to attach to a tomcat container. VS Code displayed the following message:

> Failed to connect to remote VM
> com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.ClosedConnectionException

I think the problem is that the process is not allowing external connection unless it is listening on `0.0.0.0`.

Add this environment variable to your tomcat container in your docker compose file:

```
JPDA_OPTS: "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Alternatively, you can use the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTS` to pass the variables, but then you should start catalina regularly (without the jpda).

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Comment: This worked for me. The problem may be the result of some updates in Docker Desktop for MacOS. My configuration without the 0.0.0.0 host address has been working for the past 2 years or so and then suddenly it stopped working with this exception being thrown. Thanks for the tip/1